# gulp sourcemap работает некорректно

Tags: gulp, sourcemap

Здравствуйте. К сожалению, почему-то sourcemaps отрабатывает совершенно не корректно и указывает номер строки в файле css , а не в файле scss, в итоге абсолютно теряется смысл этого модуля.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задача выглядит так:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return combiner(
        gulp.src([
                    'dev/scss/main.scss' ,
                    'dev/scss/project_components/**/*.scss'
        ]),
        debug({title: 'src'}),
        gulpIf(isDevelop, sourcemaps.init()),
        sass( sassOptions ),
        gcmq(),
        autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 4 versions']
            }),
        rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += '/css';
            path.basename = 'main' ? 'style' : path.basename;
        }),
        gulpIf(isDevelop, sourcemaps.write('.')),
        gulpIf(!isDevelop, csso()),
        newer('app'),
        gulp.dest('app'),
        debug({title: 'dest'})
    ).on('error', notify.onError(function(err){
            return {
                title: 'sass',
                message: err.message
            }
    }))

});
```

Comment: 1. В DevTools включен `Enable CSS source maps`?
2. Точно ли Gulp запускается в режиме `isDevelop`?

Comment: @YozhEzhi оба пункта да

Comment: Я бы попробовал изолировать проблему: оставил бы только `sourcemaps` и `sass` в таске и посмотрел бы результат.

Comment: @YozhEzhi странно, последовал вашему совету закомментил все кроме `sass` и `sourcemaps`, все заработало. Затем по одному начал рас комментировать, в итоге все вернулось на свои места и все работает.